# How QUARTZ JDBC JobStore selects next job from Database

Tags: jdbc, quartz

I read some documentation about quartz jdbcjobstore but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Lets assume we have 50 jobs that are waiting on the database and 10 threads in our application. My question is, which jobs will be selected from the database to process ? (Are jobs sorted by created date, or are there any configuration that I can give priority to some specific jobs)